# PowerBI Javascript API switchMode

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm working with the latest release (2.5.0) of the [PowerBI JavaScript API](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) and am not able to get the report.switchMode method to succeed.  An error is always returned with invalid view mode.

I'm calling this after the this.report has been initialized.  I've tried sending in a string for the view mode, to see if it worked like that, but that did not work either.

```
this.report.switchModel(models.ViewMode.Edit)
```

In debugging, I can see it's making the following call but I can't figure out what is an acceptable view mode parameter.

```
'/report/switchMode/' + models.ViewMode.Edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switchMode accepts string parameters "view" or "edit" (as described @ https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details#switching-between-view-and-edit-mode)

Comment: This works, thanks.  The current TypeScript definitions require a models.ViewMode enum value, but if I bypass the TypeScript def and pass in a string as you suggest it works.  Looks like the library just needs to be updated so that it sends the string value instead of the numeric value of the enum.